# Pixel shift: SPI display cause?

Tags: spi, oled, pixels

Does anyone know why my image is shifted by one pixel at this exact coordinate here every time? I am receiving the data over serial USB and writing it to the display controller RAM over the SPI interface. My current code base is here although I don’t see anything inherently wrong with how I am writing to the display with my functions. I’d be open to any potential things I can try in software to fix my issue.

https://github.com/StonedEdge/Retro-Lite-CM4-Dock

Next step I think would be to understand if the issue is related to the serial transfer or display writes. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The problem could be anywhere. Rather than pointing us to the git repo, what have you done to debug the issue? is the problem in decoding the image, or sending it to display? Have you tried writing artificial test patterns like stripes, to see what works and what does not? Can you produce a minimal example which shows a shifted image?